# Autocomplete based on user input tags and filters

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Let me first explain the use case. Consider Gmail for example, when you type in the search box "from:user sample search query", Gmail will filter the results with the specified user. My use case is similar, but what I want is, when a user types in "from:", I should show the user a list of options that could be selected. Basically some form of autocomplete as soon as I detect that a ":" has been typed.

For instance, "from:" and "to:" could be keywords that could be used in the search query. Now, I want to show a dropdown (autocomplete) when a user types in "from:" and a different dropdown when a user types in "to:". The point here being, depending on the type of search-filter, I will need to query a different API to fetch the list of values for autocomplete.

A very rough example of a full search string would be "from:abc@xyz.com after:10Nov2017 hope you are well". Once I have this string, the search part is trivial. I just want to know how to show an autocomplete box as soon as the user has typed a ":".

I have looked at a lot of Stack Overflow answers related to autocomplete. But my use case a little more complicated than the resources I have been able to find. Please redirect me to appropriate source if I have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can jquery plugin for this. Check this [`autocomplete plugin`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

As i understaood,this will fulfil your requirement. For All Complete event,you can study [`api documentation`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)